# Display values of variables taken from div html by means of d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to display the values of an array, but for some reason it shows only NaN... can somebody help with the job? thanks in advance.

```
   <td> 
    <div class="values">   
    {{ value1 }}
    </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
    <div class="values"> 
    {{ value2 }} 
    </div>    
    </td>
    
    <td>
    <div class="values"> 
    {{ value3 }}
    </div>
    </td>
```

```
  var data = d3.selectAll('.values').nodes();
  console.log(data);

  var pie = d3.pie()   //we create this variable, for the values to be readeable in the console
    .value(function(d) {return d.value; })(data);
  console.log(pie);
```

[image]

{{ Value1 }}, {{ Value2 }} and {{ Value 3 }} are being deployed correctly, this is a picture from the html:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64614134/7106086) used text input elements to create a pie chart. These elements have a property called `value`. A div does not.

When you use this, where `d` refers to an element:

```
.value(function(d) {return d.value; })(data);
```

Input elements will return a value, and the divs  will return undefined. Hence your NaN error:

```js
console.log("div.value: ",d3.select("div").node().value);
console.log("input.value: ",d3.select("input").node().value);
console.log("input value an empty string: that's the content of the field");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>text</div>
<input></input>
```

But if your div elements only contain the relevant text, then we can use something like `element.innerHtml` to get the data.

```js
console.log(d3.select("div").node().innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>50</div>
```

If you swap:

```
var pie = d3.pie()   
    .value(function(d) {return d.value; })(data);
```

With:

```
var pie = d3.pie()   
    .value(function(d) {return d.innerHTML; })(data);
```

You should have a working solution.

*Note, in both cases (input or div) the input is a string, this can cause issues depending on how you use the data, it's often a good idea to coerce the data to a number, which you can do with a unary `+`:*

```
var pie = d3.pie()   
    .value(function(d) {return +d.innerHTML; })(data);
```